# How to Solution for owl errors odoo16

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

how can i overcome this error during adding code and restarting the server the below error happend tha works previousily.
The added is module is not related

```
UncaughtPromiseError > OwlError
Uncaught Promise > An error occured in the owl lifecycle (see this Error's "cause" property)

OwlError: An error occured in the owl lifecycle (see this Error's "cause" property)
    at handleError (https://drogaerp-staging-6169684.dev.odoo.com/web/assets/471-9924e78/web.assets_common.min.js:1212:101)
    at owl.App.handleError (https://drogaerp-staging-6169684.dev.odoo.com/web/assets/471-9924e78/web.assets_common.min.js:2039:29)
    at ComponentNode.initiateRender (https://drogaerp-staging-6169684.dev.odoo.com/web/assets/471-9924e78/web.assets_common.min.js:1520:19)

Caused by: RPC_ERROR: Odoo Server Error
    at makeErrorFromResponse (https://drogaerp-staging-6169684.dev.odoo.com/web/assets/524-048114d/web.assets_backend.min.js:966:163)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (https://drogaerp-staging-6169684.dev.odoo.com/web/assets/524-048114d/web.assets_backend.min.js:973:13)
```

I want to see and give solution for the above error

Answer (score 2):

Try the feature "Regenerate Assets Bundles" via the developer tools.

Comment: This worked for me. It's in the top right menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution [from Kothiya Rajesh](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/db-restoration-error-212574):

> Looking something wrong in this module 'app_odoo_customize'.
> Try a few cases, get that module's latest code and update that module.

Comment: When copying content from somewhere else, please be sure to quote the content that isn't yours, _and_ link to the source of the content. This is called providing proper attribution and is necessary to avoid having your post deleted for plagiarism.